# Redirect to the url in j2me

Tags: java-me

I want to redirect to the given url:

http://www.silvertouch.mobi/mynino/ninoparent/paypalPayment.php?

by clicking the button in the canvas page. How can it be possible to write `platformRequest(url)` in other canvas file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing the midlet reference to the canvas and then calling the midlet processRequest(Url) method in pointerPressed?

```
public class MyCanvas extends Canvas
    {
    
    private MIDLet midlet;

    public MyCanvas(MIDlet midlet)
    {
         this.midlet = midlet;
    }

    ...
    public pointerPressed(int x, int y)
    {
        midlet.processRequest(myUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`platformRequest()` is on the MIDlet class.  Either pass the class to your canvas, or do something like this:

```
public class MyMIDlet extends MIDlet {

    public static MIDlet m;

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        MyMIDlet.m = this;
        ... other initialisation stuff
    }
}
```

Then `platformRequest()` can be called anywhere via `MyMIDlet.m.platformRequest()`.